# Why are $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle CDE$ similar?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Português: Porque $\triangle ABC$ e $\triangle CDE$ são similares na imagem abaixo?
Sendo que $M$ e $N$ são pontos médios de seus segmentos. $AD$ e $BE$ são alturas relativas.
$$$$
English: Why are $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle CDE$ similar in the picture below?
Here, $ M $ and $ N $ are midpoints of its segments, and  $AD$ and $ BE $ are heights.

Português: Se eu conseguisse mostrar que $\angle BAC =\angle EDC$, é possível?$$$$
English: If I could show that $\angle BAC = \angle EDC$ is possible?
[image: Triangle ABC]

Comment: Both triangles have a common angle. This is not enough for similarity. It would suffice, for example, if $\,ED//AB\,$

Comment: @marcelolpjunior, is $DE|| AB?$

Comment: @DonAntonio The angles $BDA$, $CEB$ are $90^{\circ}$

Comment: @marcelolpjunior, you **must** write down *all* the information  in the question!

Comment: @labbhattacharjee No, not really,

Comment: @DonAntonio $AD$ and $BE$ are height of the triangle; and $M$ and $N$ are midpoints.

Comment: @marcelolpjunior, stop writing here: write **all** the information in the question itself!

Comment: Could you write the question in English as well please?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the only permitted natural language on this website is English.

Comment: @DanielRust Translated.

Comment: @Constantine Ready Translated.

Comment: @DonAntonio Ready

Comment: @Constantine, no. When facing problems with english people is encouraged to write in his onw language, hoping somebody will be able to translate into english later.

Comment: Sum angles in triangles. $ABE=18^{\circ}$, $BDC=50^{\circ}$, $BEC=72^{\circ}$.

Comment: @AngelaRichardson, Yes, The result is $130^{\circ}$, but for what?

Comment: @AngelaRichardson $\angle BDC=180^{\circ}$ no $50^{\circ}$

Comment: I meant angle $EBC$.

Comment: @AngelaRichardson Yes, Yes, The result is $130^{\circ}$

Comment: @AngelaRichardson Did not understand anything ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Consider a circle such that $AB$ is its diameter.
- Triangles $\triangle ABE$ and $\triangle ABD$ are right.
- What do you know about inscribed angles or about angles of inscribed quadrilateral?

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: A quadrilateral inscribed opposite angles are equal ...

Comment: Nice solution! I've tried two circumferences, none worked...

Comment: @Dtldarek Entendi, obrigado ...

Answer (score 0):

Angle AED = angle ADB = 90 degrees (given)

ABDE is a cyclic quadrilateral (converse of angles in the same segment)

Angle BAC = angle EDC (ext. angle cyclic quad)

Similarly, angle ABC = angle DEC

angle C = angle C (common)

Triangle ABC ~ triangle DEC (AAA)

Note1. M and N has nothing to do with this question.

Note2. It is “Triangle ABC ~ triangle DEC” but not “Triangle ABC ~ triangle CDE”. The vertices must match correspondingly.